# Converting to set 'before' starting loop is faster in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops, for-loop

I have a large 1D list `arr1` of length 100000 which may contain duplicates and another list `arr2` which contains many of the elements in `arr1` but cannot have duplicates. I wish to append all the elements of `arr1` that are also in `arr2` into a third list `arr3`:

```py
file = []
with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        file.append(line.strip().split(' '))

arr1 = file[1]     # 2nd line of input file
arr2 = file[2]     # 3rd line of input file

arr2 = set(arr2)
arr3 = [element for element in arr1 if element in arr2]
```

Works fine. But when I try:

```py
arr3 = [element for element in arr1 if element in set(arr2)]
```

as apposed to the last two lines, I would expect the same exact result because they appear to be the same, but it takes forever to run this way. Are these somehow different?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17TdGBhGYLKsJDl-Njk498zYnZPJG6SsA/view?usp=sharing) is the input file.

Comment: The slow version is converting `arr2` to a set once per element in `arr1`.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes sense.  l always thought that the first line executes/initiates the loop, and the loop technically starts from the line after that; perhaps I was wrong? And even so, it's still so MUCH slower it's hard to believe it takes so long to convert a list to a set!

Comment: It becomes a little more clear when you break down the comprehension. It has to check the if condition for every element it hits `arr1`. Your conditional *includes* the conversion to a set. Thus you recreate the set each time you go over an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the if statement is running on every iteration - thus the conversion to set happens on every iteration.

You need to convert to set before the comparison loop is the solution.